# How can I match color palettes across different seaborn plots?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to make a pie chart and a barplot (displot) that use the same colour label across both plots, but I don't know how to do that.

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame([['d7d1b050-0e48-4c00-8061-c78817155b72',
  '42773088-e38f-4578-bc2a-69d1797a90eb',
  11,
  'groupA'],
 ['962c397d-a8f8-4f1c-a589-ecf74a7da62d',
  'b5baafb0-f6d4-4b4e-bc76-1287614b985d',
  10,
  'groupA'],
 ['a90fde40-9b9f-466e-bd5e-a40325b5fc9d',
  'b3fba007-aef5-4a5f-a53b-94eb0705d953',
  11,
  'groupB'],
 ['22ebb056-603c-4f66-8240-8c54e8043509',
  'b780fa66-addd-48c0-8db4-d755ebd351b8',
  10,
  'groupC'],
 ['52ffd64c-a5c1-4cd5-89c8-c1dcb8bd24b2',
  '37482cb7-c354-4b4b-92b6-2aaa62811e5b',
  10,
  'groupA'],
 ['55524169-f159-4c31-b939-bb00e1cba804',
  '34a9ff63-ea75-473d-ab89-9a92c3f4a8d9',
  10,
  'groupB'],
 ['2027d9d0-1e29-4d1f-969a-995a47f12052',
  '875488ea-85a2-47cb-b1ea-62003bbce80a',
  10,
  'groupA'],
 ['10d9c9fb-b5dd-4581-b148-a6198abecec1',
  '3f4b0604-513a-424b-98a3-e788ab3daa97',
  11,
  'groupD'],
 ['1c1e183b-6459-41bd-99aa-5f89b375006a',
  '53dd2ffd-c9b0-49c3-9275-190716c78799',
  10,
  'groupB'],
 ['31030ded-64a7-4854-8042-585605141e71',
  'f0514527-2d7b-4cad-a36f-f21e3425093c',
  10,
  'groupD'],
 ['cdfd5a0c-dd8c-4546-ba31-c2f021fb4859',
  '1ed007fe-d4f7-41bc-8f3c-b163c57f8a1f',
  11,
  'groupE'],
 ['66bd16a5-b514-4d8a-ad7a-afb8921f7dd2',
  'a2e9f137-bba5-46ec-8b13-7b17821de735',
  10,
  'groupB'],
 ['3cdb21d9-be3c-4723-bf28-0a7769d492b4',
  '9a6f1516-54a0-4dda-83d7-e05311e87ff5',
  10,
  'groupE'],
 ['d25f4cb2-3bf7-4898-a8a3-91d9e1b58576',
  '716a7732-6bcd-478d-87f9-c13cd83eaf66',
  11,
  'groupA'],
 ['e95134fd-7ce2-4e88-808c-e5abf13a4892',
  'c021c21b-7bab-4e1f-9ff0-4dfc584263b8',
  11,
  'groupE'],
 ['e13da005-1033-466f-b984-48fdfa0988f2',
  '5bcc0651-0775-4fa5-b521-ac90e0a33b1c',
  10,
  'groupB'],
 ['b60ee53d-e4fc-4e37-aa1c-df67f66e304e',
  '592adca4-6fa6-48c3-be97-2357250d736d',
  10,
  'groupD'],
 ['c1d47246-838f-418a-a92d-7b5150122775',
  'ff5d180c-cca9-474a-974e-e18c35cab912',
  10,
  'groupA'],
 ['fc129686-f7cd-407a-aca3-68f86c52af41',
  'a18dfc3a-2ce6-43f7-a21f-4c7371cff2b6',
  11,
  'groupE'],
 ['191af645-cb9e-408a-af2e-b6826f7177b9',
  'd430610b-b7da-42cb-aa93-c7f94774093c',
  10,
  'groupA']])

temp_df.columns = ['clickId', 'sessionId', 'month','group']

temp_df.groupby(['group']).agg({'sessionId':'count'}).plot.pie(y='sessionId');

sns.displot(data=temp_df[['sessionId', 'month', 'group']].drop_duplicates(), x='date', hue='group',  stat='count', multiple="stack")
```

Those two plots will use different color palettes, and what I would like is for each level within group to have the same colour for both the displot and the pie chart.

Any idea how I would do that?

Comment: This code doesn't run

Comment: As your code is currently written the last line `sns.displot` throws `ValueError: Could not interpret value \`date\` for parameter \`x\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the same colors (`plt.cm.tab10`) in both cases.  You might want to set alpha to 1. Note that you need `discrete=True` for the histogram.

To make sure that the same order is used everywhere, `temp_df['group'] = pd.Categorical(temp_df['group'])` can be used. Or `temp_df['group'] = pd.Categorical(temp_df['group'], ['groupA', 'groupB', 'groupC', 'groupD', 'groupE'])` if the exact ordering is important. By default, the order of appearance in the dataframe (or in the subset) is used.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

temp_df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['d7d1b050-0e48-4c00-8061-c78817155b72', '42773088-e38f-4578-bc2a-69d1797a90eb', 11, 'groupA'],
    ['962c397d-a8f8-4f1c-a589-ecf74a7da62d', 'b5baafb0-f6d4-4b4e-bc76-1287614b985d', 10, 'groupA'],
    ['a90fde40-9b9f-466e-bd5e-a40325b5fc9d', 'b3fba007-aef5-4a5f-a53b-94eb0705d953', 11, 'groupB'],
    ['22ebb056-603c-4f66-8240-8c54e8043509', 'b780fa66-addd-48c0-8db4-d755ebd351b8', 10, 'groupC'],
    ['52ffd64c-a5c1-4cd5-89c8-c1dcb8bd24b2', '37482cb7-c354-4b4b-92b6-2aaa62811e5b', 10, 'groupA'],
    ['55524169-f159-4c31-b939-bb00e1cba804', '34a9ff63-ea75-473d-ab89-9a92c3f4a8d9', 10, 'groupB'],
    ['2027d9d0-1e29-4d1f-969a-995a47f12052', '875488ea-85a2-47cb-b1ea-62003bbce80a', 10, 'groupA'],
    ['10d9c9fb-b5dd-4581-b148-a6198abecec1', '3f4b0604-513a-424b-98a3-e788ab3daa97', 11, 'groupD'],
    ['1c1e183b-6459-41bd-99aa-5f89b375006a', '53dd2ffd-c9b0-49c3-9275-190716c78799', 10, 'groupB'],
    ['31030ded-64a7-4854-8042-585605141e71', 'f0514527-2d7b-4cad-a36f-f21e3425093c', 10, 'groupD'],
    ['cdfd5a0c-dd8c-4546-ba31-c2f021fb4859', '1ed007fe-d4f7-41bc-8f3c-b163c57f8a1f', 11, 'groupE'],
    ['66bd16a5-b514-4d8a-ad7a-afb8921f7dd2', 'a2e9f137-bba5-46ec-8b13-7b17821de735', 10, 'groupB'],
    ['3cdb21d9-be3c-4723-bf28-0a7769d492b4', '9a6f1516-54a0-4dda-83d7-e05311e87ff5', 10, 'groupE'],
    ['d25f4cb2-3bf7-4898-a8a3-91d9e1b58576', '716a7732-6bcd-478d-87f9-c13cd83eaf66', 11, 'groupA'],
    ['e95134fd-7ce2-4e88-808c-e5abf13a4892', 'c021c21b-7bab-4e1f-9ff0-4dfc584263b8', 11, 'groupE'],
    ['e13da005-1033-466f-b984-48fdfa0988f2', '5bcc0651-0775-4fa5-b521-ac90e0a33b1c', 10, 'groupB'],
    ['b60ee53d-e4fc-4e37-aa1c-df67f66e304e', '592adca4-6fa6-48c3-be97-2357250d736d', 10, 'groupD'],
    ['c1d47246-838f-418a-a92d-7b5150122775', 'ff5d180c-cca9-474a-974e-e18c35cab912', 10, 'groupA'],
    ['fc129686-f7cd-407a-aca3-68f86c52af41', 'a18dfc3a-2ce6-43f7-a21f-4c7371cff2b6', 11, 'groupE'],
    ['191af645-cb9e-408a-af2e-b6826f7177b9', 'd430610b-b7da-42cb-aa93-c7f94774093c', 10, 'groupA']],
    columns=['clickId', 'sessionId', 'month', 'group'])

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(14, 6))

temp_df['group'] = pd.Categorical(temp_df['group'], ['groupA', 'groupB', 'groupC', 'groupD', 'groupE'])
temp_df.columns = ['clickId', 'sessionId', 'month', 'group']
temp_df.groupby(['group']).agg({'sessionId': 'count'}).plot.pie(y='sessionId', ax=ax1)

sns.histplot(data=temp_df[['sessionId', 'month', 'group']].drop_duplicates(),
             x='month', hue='group', palette='tab10', alpha=1,
             stat='count', discrete=True, multiple="stack", shrink=0.8, ax=ax2)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
sns.despine(ax=ax2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: pie plot and histogram with same colors]

Comment: I can reproduce the results you've shown here, but when I'm working with my own non-anonymized data, the colours between the two plots don't match up.  Any idea why that might be happening? I'm going to keep digging into it, but you've got more experience than I do.

Comment: You could do `temp_df['group'] = pd.Categorical(temp_df['group'])` to fix an ordering on the groups.  What exactly is the difference you see?  Are there more groups in one vs the other?  Are the colors fully different, or just in a different order?  Are there more than 10 colors? (After 10 colors, the pie chart will start repeating colors).

Comment: The colors are not indexing the same between the two plots.  I've gone so far as to turn the plotting part of the code into a function and just changing which data is being passed- and the only difference is the number of rows.... which makes no sense to me.

But the Categorical grouping made it work!