# Is there a way to use the same pallette for 2 scatter subplots, even if the content of the dataset is not the same

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

i have an annoying problem that is i believe best demonstrated when looking at the picture below ( take a look at the legend and the missing "1".

[inconsistent colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl8i2.png)
`x1` and `x2` are the axis of the plots, `y` is the class to which the data-point belongs. ( this is a plot of a UMAP for the MNIST dataset if that

Of course i want a consistent map from the `y` to a color in the palette, but i am not sure on how to do that.

```py
import os.path 
from torch import load
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

#
#

def plotSideBySide(combinedData: pd.DataFrame, superTitle: str, path: str = None, showVisuals = False):

    dataSources = combinedData["dataSource"].unique()
    if len(dataSources)>2:
        print("ERROR: dataset contains more than 2 dataSources ")
        dataSources = dataSources[:2]

    f1 = combinedData.loc[(combinedData['dataSource']==dataSources[0])]
    f2 = combinedData.loc[(combinedData['dataSource']==dataSources[1])]

    n_colors = len(combinedData["y"].unique())
 
    
    palette = sns.color_palette("Paired",n_colors= n_colors)
    print(n_colors)   
    x1_range = (combinedData.min()["x1"], combinedData.max()["x1"])
    x2_range = (combinedData.min()["x2"], combinedData.max()["x2"])

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)


    sns.scatterplot(data=f1, x='x1', y='x2', hue='y',
                                palette=palette,alpha=.5, ax=ax1)

    sns.scatterplot(data=f2, x='x1', y='x2', hue='y',
                                palette=palette,alpha=.5, ax=ax2)

    leftTitle = f"plot for the {dataSources[0]} data"
    rightTitle = f"plot for the {dataSources[1]} data"


    for index,axis in enumerate(fig.axes):
        axis.set(
        title=[leftTitle,rightTitle][index],
        xlim=x1_range,
        ylim=x2_range,
        xlabel=None,
        ylabel=None
    )
    plt.suptitle(superTitle)
    if path!=None:
        plt.savefig(path)
    if showVisuals:
        plt.show()
```

maybe i could create 2 palletes and remove colors from it at the index, where i got no `y` values in the dataset? so then i have 2 palettes, one missing some colors "at the rigth places"

if i don't specify the palette at all, the `y` values that do not exist in the other subplot are simply omitted from both plots.

Comment: You could try `sns.scatterplot(..., hue_order=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])`

Comment: Another approach would be to create both plots together via `sns.lmplot(data=combinedData, kind='scatter', col='dataSource', x=...,y=..., hue=.., palette=..., fit_reg=False)`. Such approach would let seaborn do all the filtering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I match color palettes across different seaborn plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70385522/how-can-i-match-color-palettes-across-different-seaborn-plots)

Comment: The duplicate creates a palette for the all the unique categories to be used for hue, from multiple datasets. Therefore, the plots for each dataset will be colored appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to ensure that two different plots use the same color mappings would be to define a dictionary palette where the keys represent a union of the two sets of levels. Then pass that to the `palette` parameter when you create each plot.